# Weather extension showing both Celcius and Fahrenheit

Tags: macos

In the summary, the weather is displayed in Fahrenheit units, whereas the city shows Celcius.

How can I make sure that the Mac weather extension shows both values in the same unit system?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think they're displaying °F & °C? They're not equivalents. Best guess is one is simply not updating correctly - something I've seen a lot through the Mojave betas

Comment: Are you sure those are the same cities?  13F is not  2C (nor is 2F = 13C in case i have it wrong).